# Extend Parent Child Hierarchy records in Oracle to display the root record of the Parent record

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here's my data:

```
SalesEmp SalesMgr Trty
  002      009     1
  002      009     2
  003      009     3
  009      010     9
  010    (null)   10
```

I am able to create hierarchies using Oracle Hierarchy (CONNECT_BY_ROOT & PRIOR) and get the output as below and store it in a table (say T1):

```
SalesEmp Trty LVL
   002    1    1
   002    2    1
   003    3    1
   009    1    2
   009    2    2
   009    3    2
   009    9    2
   010    1    3
   010    2    3
   010    3    3
   010    9    2
   010    10   1
```

For processing the records further in the application, I wish to know the child record mgr's have derived their territories from. Like:-

```
SalesEmp Trty LVL Child_Record
   002    1    1     (null)
   002    2    1     (null)
   003    3    1     (null)
   009    1    2      002
   009    2    2      002
   009    3    2      003
   009    9    1      (null)
   010    1    3      002
   010    2    3      002
   010    3    3      003
   010    9    2      009
   010    10   1      (null)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you only need to add `prior emp` as selected column:

```
-- sample data
with t(emp, mgr, trty) as (
    select '002', '009', 1 from dual union all
    select '002', '009', 2 from dual union all
    select '003', '009', 3 from dual union all
    select '009', null,  9 from dual )
-- end of sample data
select emp, connect_by_root(trty) trty, level, prior emp as child
  from t connect by emp = prior mgr
  order by level, emp, trty, prior emp
```

Result:

```
EMP       TRTY      LEVEL CHILD
--- ---------- ---------- -----
002          1          1 
002          2          1 
003          3          1        -- missing in your output
009          9          1        -- different level
009          1          2 002
009          2          2 002
009          3          2 003
```

... but the row I marked is at level one, so I'm not sure if this is your typo or if I didn't catch your logic. Also row for emp `003` is missing. If it's not typo then please show your query which produced first output (`T1`).

**Edit:**

> For level 3, the child is shown as 009 for the child records (...) I
>   want it to be the root.

So please use `connect_by_root` for child column also. This query returns values as listed in your example in column `child2`:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1254)</sup>**

```
select emp, connect_by_root(trty) trty, level, 
       prior emp as child1,
       connect_by_root(emp) child2
  from t connect by emp = prior mgr
  order by level, emp, trty, prior emp
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran this query and modified it to include a level 3. 

    `EMP  MGR TRTY
    009    010    9
    010     null   10`



For level 3, the child is shown as 009 for the child records.
   ` 010 10 1 
    010 9 2 009
    010 2 3 009
    010 1 3 009
    010 3 3 009`



I want it to be the root. (I hope I am not confusing you.)
  ` 010 10 1 
    010 9 2 009
    010 2 3 002
    010 1 3 002
    010 3 3 003`

Comment: Thanks! This worked as expected for levels 2 & above. :)

Accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you - you can LEFT JOIN your original table to your hierarchy query, connecting their TRTY and your querys' SalesEmp to original tables' SalesMng:

```
SELECT your_query.salesemp,
       your_query.trty, 
       your_query.lvl, 
       orig_table.salesemp
  FROM your_query
  LEFT JOIN orig_table ON (orig_table.salesmgr = your_query.salesemp AND orig_table.trty = your_query.trty)
 ORDER BY your_query.salesemp, your_query.trty, your_query.lvl, orig_table.salesemp
```

Comment: Goran, this worked for me as expected. I was able to get the results I wanted. However, the issue is that it's working only till level 2.

Comment: @Bhavesh looking at your  data I wasn't aware there can me more then 2 levels. Is there known max for levels?

Comment: Yes, 5. These are territory groups in a country and the way they have been distributed, the max is 5. And sorry, about the sample data, I shared an example  of data I was working on at the time.